# How to know a user as moved to a new Card in a Google Glass app?

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk, cardscrollview

Is there a way for the *CardScrollView* or *CardScrollAdapter* to let me know **when the user moves from one card to another**?

Initially I was using the *GestureDetector* to detect swipes to the left or right, but in Glass applications users can use, e.g., two-finger swipes to quickly pan and move to a distant card (or even voice controls).

There must be a better way to know exactly when a new card is displayed than to track all these directional events.

I know *CardScrollView.getSelectedItemPosition()* gives me the current card in view, but not exactly when a new card is displayed.

I also thought that *CardScrollAdapter.getView()* would run every time a new card is displayed, but in Glass applications it runs once in the beginning of the activity execution.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is actually in the documentation as suggested by @EntryLevelDev

> CardScrollView notifies you with the following listener interfaces that are inherited from AdapterView:
>
> AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener - An item is selected after the user finishes scrolling through the list and settles on an item.

from: https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/widget/CardScrollView#onAttachedToWindow()

Answer (score 0):

My Glass is somewhere in my storage so I can't test this now but you can try onDetachedToWindow and onAttachedToWindow. Probably something like this:

```
private View buildView() {
    CardBuilder card = new CardBuilder(this, CardBuilder.Layout.TEXT);

    card.setText(R.string.whatever);

    View view = card.getView();
    view.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View v) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View v) {

        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Also [Card lifecycle](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/card-scroller) might give you some idea.